# MySQL: Export table containing columns of type BLOB using the function LOAD_FILE

Tags: mysql

How I (or What tool) can export data table with BLOB type fields so, that there would be sql script like

```
INSERT INTO table (id, image) VALUES (1, LOAD_FILE('dir/image_1')) 
INSERT INTO table (id, image) VALUES (2, LOAD_FILE('dir/image_2')) 
INSERT INTO table (id, image) VALUES (3, LOAD_FILE('dir/image_3'))
...
```

instead of

```
INSERT INTO table (id, image) VALUES (1, '0x89504E470D0A1A....') 
INSERT INTO table (id, image) VALUES (2, '0xFFD8FFE000104A....') 
INSERT INTO table (id, image) VALUES (3, '0xFFDD0A1004E470....')
...
```

and the set of files (dir/image_1, dir/image_2,...) received from each BLOB in output.